# Dirichlet integral confusion

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, integration

This is a small confusion about a theorem of Ingham.(*) I will add more if detail if necessary but I think my confusion is in here.

In the last line he has

$$f(s) > \int_1^X\frac{c(x)}{x^{\alpha}}e^{(\alpha-s)\log x}dx = \int_1^X\frac{c(x)}{x^s}dx$$

in which $c(x)$ is bounded and integrable over any finite interval, and of constant sign for sufficiently large x, $s\leq \alpha.$ His $f(s)$ is the function represented by the integral (i.e., the Dirichlet integral).

If $\alpha = s$ this is trivially true. Why would it be true otherwise? I seem to arrive at something like

$$e^{\alpha - s} = x^{\alpha - s}  $$ and conclude it need not be true unless $s = \alpha.$

If it matters, $\alpha$ is greater than the putative singularity of the Dirichlet integral.

It occurs to me that maybe he meant $\geq$ instead of $=$ which would not harm the theorem, but it's Ingham and my algebra is the first suspect.

Thanks for any assistance.

(*) The Distribution of Prime Numbers, Ingham, Theorem H, p.88-89.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation between integrals rightside follows:

$$x^{-\alpha}e^{(\alpha-s)\log x}=x^{-s}\Leftrightarrow x^{-\alpha}e^{(\alpha\log x-s\log x)}=x^{-s} \Leftrightarrow x^{-\alpha}x^{\alpha}e^{(-s\log x)}=x^{-s}$$

and should be true.